# Spring AOP pointcut for annotated argument

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

Say I have a method like so:

```
public void method(@CustomAnnotation("value") String argument)
```

Is there a pointcut expression that could select all methods with arguments annotated with @CustomAnnotation?  If so is there a way I could get access go the "value" argument?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On selecting your arguments :

```
@Before("execution(* *(@CustomAnnotation (*)))")
public void advice() {
System.out.println("hello");
}
```

ref : http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-61308.html

On getting the annotation param :

```
MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
Method method = signature.getMethod();
Annotation[][] methodAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
```

Will get you the annotations which you can iterate and use instanceof to find your bound annotation. I know thats hacky but afaik this is the only way supported currently.

Comment: You need to add a space after the annotation i.e. @CustomAnnotation (*)

Answer (score 11):

To match **1..N** annotated arguments **regardless of their position** use

**Edit 2020-12-3**: Simplified version from @sgflt

```
@Before("execution(* *(.., @CustomAnnotation (*), ..))")
public void advice(int arg1, @CustomAnnotation("val") Object arg2) { ... }
```

Comment: It is overcomplicated. Just `execution(* *(.., @CustomAnnotation (*), ..))` is sufficient.

Comment: what if the method has multiple annotations like:
```public void advice(int arg1, @CustomAnnotation("val") @Custom2Annotation2("val") Object arg2) { ... }```
will it be parsed too?

Comment: EDIT: actually it works with any amount of annotations I was just forgetting to put the "@Component" annotation on the aspect class!

Answer (score 7):

Just to complete the last answer:

```
@Before(value="execution(* *(@CustomAnnotation (*), ..)) && args(input, ..)")
public void inspect(JoinPoint jp, Object input) {
        LOGGER.info(">>> inspecting "+input+" on "+jp.getTarget()+", "+jp.getSignature());
}
```

will match a method where (one of) the argument of the method **is annotated with** `@CustomAnnotation`, for example:

```
service.doJob(@CustomAnnotation Pojo arg0, String arg1);
```

In contrast to

```
@Before(value="execution(* *(@CustomAnnotation *, ..)) && args(input, ..)")
public void inspect(JoinPoint jp, Object input) {
            LOGGER.info(">>> inspecting "+input+" on "+jp.getTarget()+", "+jp.getSignature());
    }
```

which will match methods where (one of) the **argument's class is annotated with** `@CustomAnnotation`, for example:

```
service.doJob(AnnotatedPojo arg0, String arg1);
```

where the pojo is declared as follows:

```
@CustomAnnotation
public class AnnotatedPojo {
}
```

All the difference lies in the `@CustomAnnotation (*)` vs. `@CustomAnnotation *` in the pointcut declaration.

Comment: Are you sure about "one of arguments"? Will it match `service.doJob(String arg0, @CustomAnnotation Pojo arg1);`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one parameter in method you should use also two dots for mathing any number of parameters (zero or more)

```
@Before("execution(* *(@CustomAnnotation (*), ..))")
public void advice() {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the Spring Docs:

```
@Before("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
public void audit(Auditable myAnnotation) {
  AuditCode code = auditable.value();
  // ...
}
```

Which works well for me, without any need to manipulate the method signature.

Note: If you're using a named pointcut, because pointcut names can be overloaded, you must supply matching (parameter name and order) signatures.

```
@Before("goodAdvise(myAnnotation)")
public void audit(Auditable myAnnotation) {
  String value = auditable.value();
  // ...
}

@Pointcut("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
public void goodAdvise(Auditable myAnnotation) { 
  //empty
}
```

Comment: The `@annotation` pointcut refers to the annotations on the method, not on the parameters.