# Spring boot create a custom annotation to get logged in user?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations, annotation-processing

I have a entity model called `User`. I have implemented `UserDetailsService` and used it in WebSecurityConfig like this. Removed unnecessary code for brevity.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Now at any place during a request-response, I can use this code to get the currently logged in user

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String username = auth.getName();
// now use some jpa logic to retrive User entity using above username
```

Now my question is, is there any way to create a custom AOP or annotation that gives me access to logged in user so that I can use it anywhere like in my controller as shown below?

```
public class LoginController {
    public String response(@CurrentUser User user) {
        // do logic once you have access to logged in user with help of @CurrentUser annotation
    }
}
```

So like in the above example, can I create an annotation `@CurrentUser` that gives me currently logged in user(if not throws an exception, which I can catch in controller advice)?

Note: How I get the user is up to me. In the above example I am using authentcation.getName() and then querying my db to build User entity. But I can use any other way to do so. I just want to create an annotation like CurrentUser and then add the code (of retrieving the user) behind it.

Comment: search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247116/spring-aop-pointcut-for-annotated-argument and there are multiple ways of retrieving user information https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Comment: To whomsoever downvoted the question, could you please let me know what's the reason? Is this approach dangerous with regards to security or has some serious performance implications? Or did I frame the question badly? If so let me know so I can improve these questions from next time.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Yes I know how to retrieve the user. I am looking to create an easy to use annotation for that. and thanks will look into that aop link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following bean:

(change `UserDetail` if you are using a different entity for the principal).

```
  @Bean
  public Function<UserDetails, User> fetchUser() {
    return (principal -> {
      String name = principal.getUsername()
      //do JPA logic
      return ...
    });
  }
```

Then set-up the `@CurrentUser` annotation as followed:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "@fetchUser.apply(#this)", errorOnInvalidType=true)
public @interface CurrentUser {}
```

Comment: No explanations just ”copy paste this”

Comment: @Blurr Thanks. This works. Wish there was explanation so that I could learn the pros and cons of this approach though.